# How to create a dictionary nested dictionaries?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dictionary that I want to use to store keys with dictionaries as values.
Essentially, using the below screenshot of my table of data, I want to have the dictionary (in json view) as:

```
{'Folder/PU01': {'PLCName':'PLCCC', 'DeviceName': 'fasasd', 'Description': '', '....'}
{'Folder/PU02': {'PLCName':'', 'DeviceName': '', 'Description': '', '....'}
etc...
```

[image]
I have the code below that's essentially creating this, however the very bottom line above the Next is where it's going wrong `udtInstancesCurrent.Add deviceTagPath, udtInstanceParamsCurrent`
This is assigning the `udtInstanceParamsCurrent` dictionary to the `udtInstanceCurrent` key, but because it's a reference to the dictionary and not a copy, it then gets overwritten the next time the loop goes around.

My question is: how can I set the value of the dictionary key in `udtInstanceCurrent` to a copy of the `udtInstanceParamsCurrent` dictionary and not a reference to the original?

```
Dim udtInstancesCurrent As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim udtInstanceParamsCurrent As Scripting.Dictionary
    
Set udtInstancesCurrent = New Scripting.Dictionary
Set udtInstanceParamsCurrent = New Scripting.Dictionary
'''' SAVE PARAMETER VALUES ''''
' For each udt instance tag path, add its param value into a dictionary to save its values
For Each udtTagPathCell In Range(.Cells(INSTANCES_ROW_HEADERS + 1, INSTANCES_COL_UDTTAGPATH), .Cells(INSTANCES_ROW_HEADERS, INSTANCES_COL_UDTTAGPATH).End(xlDown))
    udtTagPath = udtTagPathCell.Value
    deviceName = .Cells(udtTagPathCell.Row, INSTANCES_COL_DEVICENAME)
    deviceParentPath = .Cells(udtTagPathCell.Row, INSTANCES_COL_DEVICEPARENTPATH)
    deviceTagPath = deviceParentPath & "/" & deviceName
    Row = udtTagPathCell.Row
    udtInstanceParamsCurrent.RemoveAll
        
    ' For each parameter defined, add into a dictionary
    For Each param In Range(.Cells(Row, INSTANCES_COL_PARAMSSTART), .Cells(Row, .Cells(INSTANCES_ROW_HEADERS, 1).End(xlToRight).Column))
        paramName = .Cells(INSTANCES_ROW_HEADERS, param.Column)
                            
        udtInstanceParamsCurrent.Add paramName, param.Value
    Next
        
    ' TODO: Dictionary is being overwritten. need to set this to a new instance of the dictionary
    udtInstancesCurrent.Add deviceTagPath, udtInstanceParamsCurrent
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out.. I just need to set the `udtInstanceParamsCurrent` to a new dictionary within the for loop instead of outside of it.

```
Dim udtInstancesCurrent As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim udtInstanceParamsCurrent As Scripting.Dictionary
    
Set udtInstancesCurrent = New Scripting.Dictionary

'''' SAVE PARAMETER VALUES ''''
' For each udt instance tag path, add its param value into a dictionary to save its values
For Each udtTagPathCell In Range(.Cells(INSTANCES_ROW_HEADERS + 1, INSTANCES_COL_UDTTAGPATH), .Cells(INSTANCES_ROW_HEADERS, INSTANCES_COL_UDTTAGPATH).End(xlDown))
    Set udtInstanceParamsCurrent = New Scripting.Dictionary

    udtTagPath = udtTagPathCell.Value
    deviceName = .Cells(udtTagPathCell.Row, INSTANCES_COL_DEVICENAME)
    deviceParentPath = .Cells(udtTagPathCell.Row, INSTANCES_COL_DEVICEPARENTPATH)
    deviceTagPath = deviceParentPath & "/" & deviceName
    Row = udtTagPathCell.Row
    udtInstanceParamsCurrent.RemoveAll
        
    ' For each parameter defined, add into a dictionary
    For Each param In Range(.Cells(Row, INSTANCES_COL_PARAMSSTART), .Cells(Row, .Cells(INSTANCES_ROW_HEADERS, 1).End(xlToRight).Column))
        paramName = .Cells(INSTANCES_ROW_HEADERS, param.Column)
                            
        udtInstanceParamsCurrent.Add paramName, param.Value
    Next
        
    ' TODO: Dictionary is being overwritten. need to set this to a new instance of the dictionary
    udtInstancesCurrent.Add deviceTagPath, udtInstanceParamsCurrent
Next
```